# SQLite JDBC PRAGMA setting

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, connection-pooling, pragma

I am trying to set PRAGMA foreign_key = ON; in sqlite database. I code some software in java using jdbc driver for sqlite, this one: http://www.xerial.org/trac/Xerial/wiki/SQLiteJDBC.

I am also using connection pooling to speed up queries for DB. I am using this library: 
http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/.

Up to this point, all is good. Now, I need to set PRAGMA setting, concretely PRAGMA foreign_key = ON; before creating tables, because I need to be sure about consistency between some columns in db.

When I create DB, it is automatically set to OFF. So I have to turn it on in order to use it.

But I do not know how to do it, the way I am preparing poolable data source is like this:

```
    public static DataSource getDataSource(String connectURI) {
GenericObjectPool connectionPool = new GenericObjectPool(null);
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
    new DriverManagerConnectionFactory(connectURI, null);
PoolableConnectionFactory poolableConnectionFactory =
    new PoolableConnectionFactory(connectionFactory, connectionPool, null, null, false, true);
DataSource dataSource = new PoolingDataSource(connectionPool);
return dataSource;
}
```

But I do not know how to set that pragma properly, I found that this one is possible:

```
SQLiteConfig config = new SQLiteConfig();
config.enforceForeignKeys(true);
```

But I do not know how to use it in connection with that poolable tricky settings ...

Any ideas?

Comment: This [link][1] might be helpful.


  [1]: http://code-know-how.blogspot.ru/2011/10/how-to-enable-foreign-keys-in-sqlite3.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is more of a DBCP question than SQLite. I agree, there has to be a place somewhere in DBCP to set/update the config for a given data source. I would expect to see it in the PoolingDataSource class, but of course its not there.

One option to consider is to use a jdbc pooling library that leverages the ConnectionPoolDataSource interface. If so, you can use the [SQLiteConnectionPoolDataSource](http://sourceforge.net/p/sqlite-connpool/) to set up a connection pool like this:

```
  //Set config
    org.sqlite.SQLiteConfig config = new org.sqlite.SQLiteConfig();
    config.enforceForeignKeys(true);


  //Create JDBC Datasource
    SQLiteConnectionPoolDataSource dataSource = new SQLiteConnectionPoolDataSource();
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:sqlite:" + db.toString().replace("\\", "/"));
    dataSource.setConfig(config);
```

Note that there is an extension to DBCP called [DriverAdapterCPDS](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/api-1.2.2/org/apache/commons/dbcp/cpdsadapter/DriverAdapterCPDS.html). It is an implementation of the ConnectionPoolDataSource interface so in theory, you should be able to use the [SQLiteConnectionPoolDataSource](http://sourceforge.net/p/sqlite-connpool/) with DBCP .

Comment: I've tried it. It works like a charm. I am using this connection pool manager in addition to that sql library: http://www.source-code.biz/miniconnectionpoolmanager/. For me, this topic is solved.